# How to identify a string that contains only space

Tags: java, string

I have a long string and I split it by space character, in some parts there are more than one space so a space gets to become a string. I have created a for loop and trying to identify those space strings to skip them but unfortunately they cannot be found by the code that I'm using.

```
public static void main( String[] args ){  


    String s = "Monday Tuesday Wednesday 8:00       8:15       8:30       8:45       9:00       9:15       9:30       9:45       10:00 IT Service Mgt. F1.2 wkFeb2-wkMar23, wkApr13-wkMay11 IT Service Mgt. B180 wkFeb2-wkMar23, wkApr13-wkMay11 Strategic IT Mgt. F1.2 wkFeb2-wkMar23, wkApr13-wkMay11 10:15 10:30 10:45 11:00 Strategic IT Mgt. B145 wkFeb2-wkMar23, wkApr13-wkMay11   11:15   11:30   11:45   12:00     12:15     12:30     12:45     13:00 IT Service Mgt. B145 wkFeb2-wkMar23, wkApr13-wkMay11 IT Service Mgt. E7 wkFeb2-wkMar23, wkApr13-wkMay11   13:15   13:30   13:45   14:00   Sec. Penetration Testing B251 wkFeb2-wkMar23, wkApr13-wkMay11 Ent. Storage Sys. C129 wkFeb2-wkMar23, wkApr13-wkMay11 14:15   14:30   14:45   15:00   Ent. Storage Sys. C129 wkFeb2-wkMar23, wkApr13-wkMay11 15:15   15:30   15:45   16:00   Sec. Penetration Testing C136 wkFeb2-wkMar23, wkApr13-wkMay11 Ent. Storage Sys. C134x wkFeb2-wkMar23, wkApr13-wkMay11 16:15   16:30   16:45   17:00     17:15     17:30     17:45    ";
    String[] parts = s.split(" ");
    String space = " ";
    for(int i=0; i<parts.length;i++)
    {   

        if(parts[i].charAt(0) == ' ')
        {
            System.out.println("askdfhlghlaksjdgsdasasfasfasdfasd");
        }
        if(parts[i].compareTo(" ")==0){
            System.out.print("asdfghgfdsaASDFGHGFDSASDFGHJKJHGFDSASDFGHJKJHGTFRD");
        }
        System.out.print(parts[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is "askdfhlghlaksjdgsdasasfasfasdfasd" a meaningful output message in your user's native language ?

Comment: It's just a test message...

Comment: rlemon, even if i add parts[i].matches("^\\s*$") to the if condition it still doesn't enter the if statement

Comment: First [`trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) your text, before splitting it.

Comment: I used parts[i].length(), if its 1 then it is just a space...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression for your [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) like `s.split("[ ]+")`.

`[ ]+` means match against space occurring at least once.

If you want to match space or tab occurring at least once, you can use `[\t ]+`.

If you want to skip the spaces at the beginning or end of string, use [`trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29).

Here is a [summary of Java regular expression constructs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Comment: I tried but it doesn't help..

Comment: Are you trying to get an array of "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "8:00", "8:15" and so on?

Comment: no there is more involved in it but only think is that I  am trying to identify a space character because its either a space character or a text starts after e.c 9:00  or 10:00. All I need is the data after it.

Comment: If spaces are part of your normal column content, then it is better to use something else as the delimiter like tabs. Or we could consider putting column texts with spaces inside quotation marks like "New Year's Day".

Comment: If you're generating the text file from Excel or Libre Calc, it is possible to select which delimiter to use.

Comment: I'm getting the data from a timetable website using JSoup but this is the only thing that I'm stuck on right now.

Comment: If you want to skip the spaces at the beginning or end of string, use [`trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regular expression:

```
String parts = s.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Output of `parts`:

> [Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, 8:00, 8:15, 8:30, 8:45, 9:00, ...]

Now, the above will allow tabs and other white space characters though. To eliminate them all, you can do:

```
String parts = s.trim().split(" +");
```